# How do I return mongo document where item is in an array?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the following document in a mongodb collection called "Items"

```
"_id": {
        "$oid": "5fcfa614d588d46ec44cc375"
    },
    "ProductId": {
        "$binary": {
            "base64": "LredEr/+9UGY3g5oIDWhPw==",
            "subType": "03"
        }
    },
    "ProductName": "ModelProductTest",
    "AccountId": {
        "$binary": {
            "base64": "Gzmr+JvFq0y0YRBOfkj57w==",
            "subType": "03"
        }
    },
    "Skus": [
        {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5fcfa614d588d46ec44cc376"
            },
            "ProductSkuId": {
                "$binary": {
                    "base64": "MBLj5bL6C0Cph0fMkpbDZA==",
                    "subType": "03"
                }
            },
            "ProductId": {
                "$binary": {
                    "base64": "LredEr/+9UGY3g5oIDWhPw==",
                    "subType": "03"
                }
            },
            "SkuCode": "kkss",
            "Barcode": "12345",
            "Description": "test",
            "StockQuantity": {
                "$numberInt": "2"
            },
            "Costs": [
                {
                    "_id": {
                        "$oid": "5fcfa614d588d46ec44cc378"
                    },
                    "ProductPriceId": {
                        "$binary": {
                            "base64": "81rqEsKc9k6y2IQQjE1DJg==",
                            "subType": "03"
                        }
                    },
                    "ProductSkuId": {
                        "$binary": {
                            "base64": "MBLj5bL6C0Cph0fMkpbDZA==",
                            "subType": "03"
                        }
                    },
                    "DateValidFrom": {
                        "$date": {
                            "$numberLong": "1607443988489"
                        }
                    },
                    "Cost": "33"
                },
                {
                    "_id": {
                        "$oid": "5fcfa614d588d46ec44cc379"
                    },
                    "ProductPriceId": {
                        "$binary": {
                            "base64": "aqdf9S6yUUCIZEjLY/1pvw==",
                            "subType": "03"
                        }
                    },
                    "ProductSkuId": {
                        "$binary": {
                            "base64": "MBLj5bL6C0Cph0fMkpbDZA==",
                            "subType": "03"
                        }
                    },
                    "DateValidFrom": {
                        "$date": {
                            "$numberLong": "1607443988492"
                        }
                    },
                    "Cost": "39"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5fcfa614d588d46ec44cc377"
            },
            "ProductSkuId": {
                "$binary": {
                    "base64": "XFkTknYw2Uyy2ae/F/yj1A==",
                    "subType": "03"
                }
            },
            "ProductId": {
                "$binary": {
                    "base64": "LredEr/+9UGY3g5oIDWhPw==",
                    "subType": "03"
                }
            },
            "SkuCode": "kksass",
            "Barcode": "12346",
            "Description": "test",
            "StockQuantity": {
                "$numberInt": "6"
            },
            "Costs": [
                {
                    "_id": {
                        "$oid": "5fcfa614d588d46ec44cc37a"
                    },
                    "ProductPriceId": {
                        "$binary": {
                            "base64": "hxWucmMsnkOkRb1j9/EtGA==",
                            "subType": "03"
                        }
                    },
                    "ProductSkuId": {
                        "$binary": {
                            "base64": "XFkTknYw2Uyy2ae/F/yj1A==",
                            "subType": "03"
                        }
                    },
                    "DateValidFrom": {
                        "$date": {
                            "$numberLong": "1607443988492"
                        }
                    },
                    "Cost": "31"
                },
                {
                    "_id": {
                        "$oid": "5fcfa614d588d46ec44cc37b"
                    },
                    "ProductPriceId": {
                        "$binary": {
                            "base64": "ExyZdI6suE2Zs5oRdeiK9w==",
                            "subType": "03"
                        }
                    },
                    "ProductSkuId": {
                        "$binary": {
                            "base64": "XFkTknYw2Uyy2ae/F/yj1A==",
                            "subType": "03"
                        }
                    },
                    "DateValidFrom": {
                        "$date": {
                            "$numberLong": "1607443988492"
                        }
                    },
                    "Cost": "36"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I want to get the main object and the specific sku (not all the skus) returned when I search by barcode. How do I do this in C# using the mongo driver?

Comment: Have you tried anything? This just looks like JSON. You should be able to read/parse it with little to no issue using C#.

Comment: Sorry, I was not particularly clear. I am trying to fetch it from mongo. I do not want to fetch the entire document as it could potentially be huge. I have amended my question to make it a little more clear what I need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it easily with the `AsQueryable` interface of the official driver like so:

```cs
collection.AsQueryable()
          .Where(i => i.Skus.Any(s => s.Barcode == "22222222")))
          .Select(i => new Item
          {
              Id = i.Id,
              ProductName = i.ProductName,
              Skus = i.Skus.Where(s => s.Description == "second sku")
          })
          .ToListAsync();
```

you need to do a manual projection for each property of the main entity you need returned and simply filter the Skus with a `Where` clause.

the above will get translated into an aggregation pipeline like this:

```java
[
    {
        "$match": {
            "Skus": {
                "$elemMatch": {
                    "Barcode": "22222222"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "ProductName": "$ProductName",
            "Skus": {
                "$filter": {
                    "input": "$Skus",
                    "as": "s",
                    "cond": {
                        "$eq": [
                            "$$s.Barcode",
                            "22222222"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

test program using mongodb.entities:

```js
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;
using MongoDB.Entities;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestApplication
{
public class Item : Entity
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Sku> Skus { get; set; }
}

public class Sku
{
    [ObjectId]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Barcode { get; set; }
}

public static class Program
{
    private static async Task Main()
    {
        await DB.InitAsync("test");

        await new Item
        {
            ProductName = "test product",
            Skus = new[] {
                new Sku { Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString(), Barcode = "11111111" },
                new Sku { Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString(), Barcode = "22222222" },
                new Sku { Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString(), Barcode = "33333333" }
            }
        }.SaveAsync();

        var item = await DB.Queryable<Item>()
                           .Where(i => i.Skus.Any(s => s.Barcode == "22222222"))
                           .Select(i => new Item
                           {
                               ID = i.ID,
                               ProductName = i.ProductName,
                               Skus = i.Skus.Where(s => s.Barcode == "22222222")
                           })
                           .ToListAsync();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: That is great. However I need to find the product by the barcode in the sku. If I do this I get the sku object back, not the parent. var d = _database.GetCollection<Item>("ProductItemModels");
            d.AsQueryable<Item>()
                .Where(i => i.Skus
                .Where(s => s.Barcode == barcode).Select(i => new tem
                {

                }));

Comment: @coolblue2000 i've updated my answer. `.AsQueryable().Where(i => i.Skus.Any(s => s.Barcode == "22222222")))` is the filter you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. I have the new issue of it complaining about the line "Skus = i.Skus.Where(s => s.Barcode == "22222222")" It will not accept it as Skus is a List but it also will not let me do a ToList() on it. - 'The result operation MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Expressions.ResultOperators.ListResultOperator is not supported.'

Comment: Fixed it. I now have Skus =  (List<StockPointProductSku>) i.Skus.Where(s => s.Barcode == "22222222")"

Comment: Thanks for your help.